# No videos found in . - DeepLabCut pretrained project

Tags: python

I am trying to use a DeepLabCut's pretrained project, following their code available in Google Colab, but I fail with an error:

```
No videos found in /
Perhaps change the videotype, which is currently set to: mp4
No videos found in .
Perhaps change the videotype, which is currently set to: mp4
Copying the videos
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\DLC-CPU\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\create_project\new.py:175: UserWarning: No valid videos were found. The project was not created... Verify the video files and re-create the project.
  "No valid videos were found. The project was not created... "
No videos found in .
Perhaps change the videotype, which is currently set to: mp4
Copying the videos
C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\DLC-CPU\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\create_project\new.py:175: UserWarning: No valid videos were found. The project was not created... Verify the video files and re-create the project.
  "No valid videos were found. The project was not created... "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 16, in <module>
    createlabeledvideo=True, copy_videos=True)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\DLC-CPU\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\create_project\modelzoo.py", line 176, in create_pretrained_project
    config = auxiliaryfunctions.read_config(cfg)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\DLC-CPU\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut\utils\auxiliaryfunctions.py", line 188, in read_config
    "Config file is not found. Please make sure that the file exists and/or that you passed the path of the config file correctly!"
FileNotFoundError: Config file is not found. Please make sure that the file exists and/or that you passed the path of the config file correctly!
```

The code for it is simply:

```
import os
import deeplabcut
from deeplabcut.utils import auxiliaryfunctions, auxfun_models

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_path = os.path.join('data', 't_video5936177301707294584downsampled.mp4')
    path_config_file = deeplabcut.create_pretrained_project('HorsePoseDemo', 'Valeria',  
                                                            video_path, videotype='mp4', 
                                                            working_directory=os.getcwd(),
                                                            model='horse_sideview', analyzevideo=True, 
                                                            createlabeledvideo=True, copy_videos=True)
```

I would expect the `create_pretrained_project` somehow take care of the configs and other things, but it seems that just does not locate the video for some reason, which is, as relative to the path at which I call this file with `python demo.py`, is in the `data` directory.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docstring](https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut/blob/master/deeplabcut/create_project/modelzoo.py) for `dlc.create_pretrained_project` the input param `videos` should be a "list of strings containing the full paths of the videos to include in the project." Passing a list of a single file path solved the issue for me.